# capture a photo from camera and display it in image view in another activity

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I wanna display the captured photo from camera on another activity in image view. But it has to be full quality. Please,tell me how to do it. This is my code :

MainActivity.class

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1888;
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            {
               Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(),returnUri);
                    Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowCameraPhotoActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("image",bitmapImage);
                    startActivity(i);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
           }

                }
```

ShowPhotoCameraActivity.class:

```
  ImageView showPhoto = (Imageview) findViewById(R.id.image);
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");
   if (showPhoto != null) {
        showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Utils Class.

```
 public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == Config.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }  else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}


public static  File persistImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    File filesDir = AppSingleton.getContext().getFilesDir();
    File imageFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".png");

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(AppSingleton.getContext().getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
    }
    return imageFile;
}



public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
```

MainActivity

```
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    private Uri fileUri;
    Bitmap bitmap2;


 /**
 * Cature image
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = Utils.getOutputMediaFileUri(Config.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String imagePath = getImagePath(data.getData());
            if (imagePath != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(IMAGE_PATH, imagePath);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity

in onCreate()

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled=true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_PATH"), options);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: @G.Al create singleton class with context or move these methods to your acitivty

Comment: sorry about not mentioning earlier,but it gives me an error also at IMAGE_DiRECTORY_NAME and MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE

Comment: @G.Al     public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "OwoCar"; just define these variables

Comment: I don't know. It's not working,there are a lot of errors..maybe you have a simpler solution.

Comment: @G.Al i'll answer you later if you won't't find solution before. Actually this is working code just some problems with classes distribution i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123655/discussion-between-g-al-and-anton-kazakov).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this. for opening camera.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

after taking photo, you collect the data in the onActivityResult() method like this way.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String filePath;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

  Intent intent = new Intent(anotherActivity.class)
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse ("file://" + filePath));
  startActivity(intent);
 }
```

and then new activity do like this.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

Comment: Value filePath is always null !!

Comment: and what is "imgUri" ?

Comment: I replaced imgUri with uri !! but again it shows me an error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not aligned, and causing crash.

Global variable : `private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1888;`

Function to call camera :

```
      private void camera(){
      Intent intent = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    ? new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE)
                    : new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);
      }
```

Another `@Override` method for Result Handling `onActivityResult`:

```
      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtra("data");

                Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowCameraPhotoActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("image",bitmapImage);
                startActivity(i);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
       }
      }
```

Must declare permission for `Camera` in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: can you explain me MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this,.....) it shows me an error

Comment: Use this `Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), returnUri);`

Comment: @G.Al add try catch block and run, It occurs because some time it may throw exception. So add try catch block around the code (click on red bulb it will add automatically ;) )

Comment: Yes yes .. I figured that out 10 seconds after i posted the comment :P . But again it shows an error.. I literally tried everything :/ Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.ga.photoeditor/com.example.ga.photoeditor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference

Comment: Post your code again, as it is I'll compile here and will let u know. Update your code in question

Comment: check I updated my code, it will work. Use permission for camera in manifest and use `Uri` in try block.

Comment: It doesn't work .. I have other problems ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622694/how-to-select-an-image-from-gallery-or-to-capture-a-photo-and-then-to-display-it/39623041#39623041

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase to store the image and use image url to load the image in any activity of your choice
I used this tut for my app https://youtu.be/s1aOlr3vbbk
you can use picasso or glide libraries to load your images

```
 private DatabaseReference reference;
 private ImageView image_profile;

image_profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Query query = reference.child("Pictures");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String url = snapshot.child("imageurl").getValue().toString();

                if (!url.isEmpty())
                {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(url)
                            .into(image_profile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```