# How to select an image from gallery or to capture a photo and then to display it in another activity full quality

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera, android-bitmap

I have two image buttons,for camera and gallery . If you select "camera" you can capture a photo from camera and then that photo has to be displayed in another activity in image view. If you select "gallery" then you have to select a photo from gallery and then that photo has to be display it in another activity . My code for gallery works fine . I created two others activities(with the same layout), one for gallery and the other for camera. But the code for camera doesn't work . Here is my code :
MainActivity :

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static int SELECT_FILE = 1;
 ImageButton take_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    ImageButton get_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);
    if (take_photo != null) {
        take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
         }
        });
    }
    //to get the photo from gallery
    if (get_photo != null) {
        get_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_FILE);
   }
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowPhotoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imagePath", imageFile.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                {
                    try {
                        Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                        Bitmap bitmapImage =    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), returnUri);
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowCameraPhotoActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("image", bitmapImage);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  }
            }}
            } }

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();

    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

ShowPhotoActivity(this is the activity for gallery):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imagePath"));

    if (showPhoto != null) {


        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());


        showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm); }
```

ShowCameraPhotoActivity(this is the activity for camera):

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");
    if (showPhoto != null) {
        showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I tried with just one other activity,but that also didn't work. In logcat it says that it happens because getRealPathFromUri(). But I don't know what . If you have any solutions or better ideas,please help me :)

logcat:

```
 Process: com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor, PID: 22360
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor/com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3840)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3883)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1426)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1477)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:473)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:426)
                                                                                  at com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.MainActivity.getRealPathFromURI(MainActivity.java:189)
                                                                                  at com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:105)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6320)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3836)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3883) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1426) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
    09-21 19:11:44.293 22360-22360/com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor I/Process:     Sending signal. PID: 22360 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code, including:

- `getRealPathFromURI()` is unreliable in general and unnecessary in this case. Pass the `Uri` itself to `ShowPhotoActivity`.
- `ShowPhotoActivity` is loading the image on the main application thread. Do not do this. Please use one of many [image loading libraries available for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), as they can load your image asychronously using the `Uri`. Personally, I use Picasso.
- You are assuming that you get a `Uri` back from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. That is not how `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` works.

Instead, replace:

```
    Uri returnUri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmapImage =    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), returnUri);
```

with:

```
    Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtra("data");
```

Comment: Thank you :) I used getRealPathFromUri() because that's the only way that the code worked. I was trying to do this first,and then I would fix the issue about the main application thread. I'll try to fix these things,and I'll tell you if this worked.